# Hatcher's Ex. 4.1.6: The Surjectivity Bit

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is Ex. 4.1.6 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*:

> If $p: (\tilde{X} , \tilde{A}, \tilde{x}_0) \rightarrow (X , A, x_0)$ is a covering space with $\tilde{A} = p^{-1} (A)$, show that the map $p_* : \pi_n (\tilde{X} , \tilde{A}, \tilde{x}_0) \rightarrow \pi_n (X , A, x_0)$ is an isomorphism for all $n > 1$.

By adapting the proof from Prop. 1.31, I think that I've been able to prove the **injectivity** bit. I wrote it down as follows:

An element of the kernel of $p_*$ is represented by a mapping $\tilde{f}_0 : (D^n , S^{n-1} , s_0) \rightarrow (\tilde{X},\tilde{A}, \tilde{x}_0)$ which is such that $f_0 = f \circ \tilde{f}_0 : (D^n , S^{n-1} , s_0) \rightarrow (X,A,x_0)$ is homotopic $\text{rel } S^{n-1}$ to a map with image contained in $\tilde{A}$. That is, there exists a homotopy $f_t : (D^n , S^{n-1} , s_0) \rightarrow (X,A, x_0)$ that begins with $f_0$ and ends with $f_1$, where $f_1$ is a map $(D^n , S^{n-1} , s_0) \rightarrow (X,A,x_0)$ where $f_1(d) \in A$ for all $d \in D^{n}$, and $f_u (s) = f_v (s)$ for all $s \in S^{n-1}$ and all $u,v \in [0,1]$.

Since $\tilde{f}_0$ lifts $f_0$, the *homotopy lifting property* kicks in, and $f_t$ lifts to a homotopy $\tilde{f}_t$ on $\tilde{X}$, starting with $\tilde{f}_0$ and ending with $\tilde{f}_1$, which is the lift of $f_1$, that is, a mapping $(D^n , S^{n-1} , s_0) \rightarrow (\tilde{X},\tilde{A}, \tilde{x}_0)$ which is such that $\tilde{f}_1 (d) \in \tilde{A}$ for all $d \in D^n$. Furthermore, since we need to have $p \circ \tilde{f}_u (s) = p \circ \tilde{f}_v (s)$ for all $u,v \in [0,1]$ and all $s \in S^{n-1}$, $p$ being a cover and $\tilde{f}_t$ being continuous tells us that we must have $\tilde{f}_u (s) = \tilde{f}_v (s)$ for all $u,v \in [0,1]$ and all $s \in S^{n-1}$. Thus, $\tilde{f}_0$ is homotopic $\text{rel } S^{n-1}$ to a map with image contained in $\tilde{A}$, so $[\tilde{f}_0] = 0$, and the kernel is trivial.

**Now, then**, the thing that I find troublesome is proving **surjectivity**. I get that since $D^n$ is simply connected, $\pi_1 (D^n, s_0) = 0$, and so, for any map $f: (D^n, s_0) \rightarrow (X,x_0)$, since $0 = f_{*} (\pi_1 (D^n, s_0)) \subseteq p_{*} (\pi_1 (\tilde{X} , \tilde{x}_0))$, $f$ lifts to a map $\tilde{f} : (D^n, s_0) \rightarrow (\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0)$.

But then, wouldn't that imply that any map $f: (D^n, S^{n-1}, s_0) \rightarrow (X,A,x_0)$ lifts to a map $\tilde{f} : (D^n, S^{n-1}, s_0) \rightarrow (\tilde{X},\tilde{A},\tilde{x}_0)$, including the case where $n=1$? And wouldn't this in turn imply that the induced map $p_* \pi_n (\tilde{X}, \tilde{A}, x_0) \rightarrow \pi_n (X,A,x_0)$ is surjective?

What am I doing wrong? Where is the reason for why this argument doesn't work for $n=1$?

Comment: Relative homotopy groups are defined for $n>1.$

Comment: Then why does Hatcher refer to $\pi_1 (X,A,x_0)$ later on in Ex. 4.1.8?

Comment: He seems to use the notion of exactness for sets as well. He explains it after the statement of Theorem 4.3. on p. 344.

Comment: Fair enough. Though my question then is, are the first relative homotopy groups not isomorphic as sets?

Comment: Hm. I don't see any problems with your argument. But this conclusion is not forgone.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that I’m asking the wrong question, and that I should first make sure that I understand *why* $\pi_1 (X, A, x_0)$ is not a group? I’ll start another wuestion for that…!